# Fiddler - Get ip address for incoming data

Tags: fiddler

Is there a way in static function OnWebSocketMessage(oMsg: WebSocketMessage) to get ip address and port for the incoming data?

In the attached picture I see oMsg can call other functions, but I do not know which one to call

I am using Fiddler Web Debugger (v4.6.2.2)

[image]